# \rowcolor and nested loops with datatool package

Tags: tables, datatool, rowcolor

I can't explain why  using `\rowcolor` into a nested `datatool` loop gives this strange behavior:
[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
1
2
3
4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{table}{table.csv}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\rowcolor{gray!50} odd
\DTLforeach*{table}{\field=Column1}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \rowcolor{gray!20} odd
        \DTLforeach*{table}{}{%
        \DTLiflastrow{}{\\ \DTLifoddrow{even}{\rowcolor{gray!20} odd}}%
        }\\
    \end{tabular}
    \DTLiflastrow{}{\\ \DTLifoddrow{even}{\rowcolor{gray!50} odd}}% 
    }\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**note**: Adding `\rowcolor{white}` into the first argument of the `\DTLifoddrow` conditional obviously solves the problem. But I would like to know why this is necessary whereas the main loop doesn't need it.